# Removing unwanted characters in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column like below :

```
  |  ColumnA    |
  +-------------+
  |    ABCD(!)  |
  | <DEFG>(23)  |
  | (MNPQ. )    |
  |    32.JHGF  |
  |    "QWERT"  |
```

Aim is to remove the special characters and produce the output as below :

```
  |  ColumnA   |
  +------------+
  |    ABCD    |
  |    DEFG    |
  |    MNPQ    |
  |    JHGF    |
  |    QWERT   |
```

Tried using the `replace` method like below, but without success :

```
df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\_]+", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

So, how can I replace the special characters using replace method in pandas?

Comment: Did you try `regex=True` in the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)-method?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is also for get numbers `\d` and `_`, so it remove only:

```
df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z]+", "")
print (df)
  ColumnA
0    ABCD
1    DEFG
2    MNPQ
3    JHGF
4   QWERT
```

Answer (score 1):

regrex should be `r'[^a-zA-Z]+'`, it means keep only the characters that are from A to Z, a-z

```
import pandas as pd

#   |  ColumnA    |
#   +-------------+
#   |    ABCD(!)  |
#   | <DEFG>(23)  |
#   | (MNPQ. )    |
#   |    32.JHGF  |
#   |    "QWERT"  |

# create a dataframe from a list 
df = pd.DataFrame(['ABCD(!)', 'DEFG(23)', '(MNPQ. )', '32.JHGF', 'QWERT'], columns=['ColumnA'])

 #   |  ColumnA   |
#   +------------+
#   |    ABCD    |
#   |    DEFG    |
#   |    MNPQ    |
#   |    JHGF    |
#   |    QWERT   |
# keep only the characters that are from A to Z, a-z 
df['ColumnB'] =df['ColumnA'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', '')

print(df['ColumnB'])
```

Result:

```
0     ABCD
1     DEFG
2     MNPQ
3     JHGF
4    QWERT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested code works fine on my installation with only extra digits so that you need to update your regex statement: **r"[^a-zA-Z]+"** If this doesn't work, then maybe try to update your pandas;

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Column A': [' ABCD(!)', '<DEFG>(23)', '(MNPQ. )', ' 32.JHGF',  '"QWERT"']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['ColumnA'] = df['ColumnA'].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z]+", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

> Output

```
  Column A
0     ABCD
1     DEFG
2     MNPQ
3     JHGF
4    QWERT
```

Comment: A typo, thanks for pointing out!